# Ramda ifElse is not executed for function with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Can somebody explain me this behavior, or is it a bug?

```
const firstTest = (a) => console.log(a, 'this will be executed');
const secTest = (a, b) => console.log(a, 'this will not be executed');

const firstIfElse = R.ifElse(R.T, firstTest, () => null);
const unexpectedIfElse = R.ifElse(R.T, secTest, () => null);

firstIfElse('logging appears as expected');
unexpectedIfElse('no logging');
```

[example in REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?const%20firstTest%20%3D%20%28a%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28a%2C%20%27this%20will%20be%20executed%27%29%3B%0Aconst%20secTest%20%3D%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28a%2C%20%27this%20will%20not%20be%20executed%27%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20firstIfElse%20%3D%20R.ifElse%28R.T%2C%20firstTest%2C%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20null%29%3B%0Aconst%20unexpectedIfElse%20%3D%20R.ifElse%28R.T%2C%20secTest%2C%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20null%29%3B%0A%0AfirstIfElse%28%27logging%20appears%20as%20expected%27%29%3B%0AunexpectedIfElse%28%27no%20logging%27%29%3B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second function is a curried binary function.  `ifElse` chooses the maximum arity of the three functions passed to it, `predicate`, `ifTrue`, and `ifFalse`.  `R.T` has arity 1, as does `() => null`, but `secTest` has arity 2, so `unexpectedIfElse` also has arity 2.

When you call `unexpectedIfElse` with 'no logging', you get back a function waiting for the (useless) `b` parameter.

There are reasons not to like this additional complexity, but there are times when it's very useful, especially for the predicate.

You can fix your issue by calling it like

```
unexpectedIfElse('no logging', 'ignored');
```

or like

```
unexpectedIfElse('no logging')('ignored')
```